# accountsGoogle publish profile picture

Tags: meteor

In Meteor I am using the `accountsGoogle` package. I am trying to use the Google profile picture on my site but as soon as a remove the `autopublish` package I need to publish and subscribe to the google part of the users collection. How would I go about doing this?

```
Meteor.publish('users', function(){
    return Meteor.user.services.google.find({});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the user document from the client-side using

```
Meteor.user()
```

Or if you really want to use a publication

```
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
    return Meteor.users.find(this.userId);
})
```

Comment: `Meteor.user()` is not returning the services.google part of the user collection unless autopublish is installed.

Comment: On my app autopublish is removed and Meteor.user() return the entire document